# Have <a> tag call a function instead of loading a new page

Tags: php, html

```
 echo('<a class="block" href="block.php" title="Block User"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <br>');
```

That is the line of code for blocking a user. But instead of using href to link to block.php can I instead call a function(that is already on the page) and simply have it to where when you click it it runs the function?

Comment: not with php, its server side, with js (AJAX) and php yes

Comment: change it in button and by `jquery` `ajax` you can do it simply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make button to that icon and call the javascript function on click . This function will take to block.php .

In place of

```
<a href = ""></a>
```

place

```
<button type="button" id="btnSend"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Now on **js**  :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSend").click(function () {      //this function will call when user click the button 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'block.php',             //url of that block.php any other if link is different
            type: 'POST',
            data: "data",                 //data if there is any 
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```